# switch div tags using javascript doesnt work in xhtml strict

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, switch-statement

Hi i need to switch between div tags, I have no idea where's the problem...
The site is XHTML strict...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var activeId = $(".active").each(function(){
       $("#content" + $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","")).show();
    });

    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
        var $tabs =$(this).closest(".tabs"); 
        $("#content" +$tabs.attr("data-lastContent")).hide();
        $(this).closest(".tabs").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active")
        var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
        $tabs.attr("data-lastContent", id);
        $("#content" + id).show();
    });

});​
```

It is a menu and some divs below I need to switch... I use the code from this post http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/24/ but with no success....

```
<div class="tabs" data-lastContent="1">
<li id="tab1" class="active"><a href="#">PROSBA</a></li>
<li id="tab2"><a href="#">PRŮVODNÍ TEXT</a></li>
<li id="tab3"><a href="#">GALERIE</a></li>
<li id="tab4"><a href="#">JAK POMOCI?</a></li>
</div>
<div id="content1" class="content"><div class="scroller">ahojjjj</div></div>
<div id="content2" class="content"><div class="scroller">nee</div></div>
<div id="content3" class="content"><div class="scroller">ahdad</div></div>
<div id="content4" class="content"><div class="scroller">ahod</div></div>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks.
Jan

Comment: and here it works with the same code http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/237/

Comment: The problem is data-attributes is HTML5. **data-lastContent**

Comment: oh, so how can i do this in xhtml?

Comment: and why it works in jsfiddle? (like a charm : http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/252/

Comment: JSFiddle supports the latest technologies and 'fills' in the gaps. It doesn't take into account server settings and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the basics...[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/24/)

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $('.content').hide(); //hide all the contents
   $('.active').show();  //show only active
    $('.tab').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //stop from linking
    $('.content').hide(); //hide all the contents
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); //remove class from current tab
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); //remove class from current content
    var id = $(this).attr('href'); //get desired content id
    $(this).addClass('selected'); //add class to clicked tab
    $('#'+id).addClass('active').show(); //add class to active content and display
    });    

});
​
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="content1" class="tab selected">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="content2" class="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="content3" class="tab">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="content4" class="tab">Tab4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="display">
    <div id="content1" class="content active">blah</div>    
    <div id="content2" class="content">blahh</div>
    <div id="content3" class="content">blahhh</div>
    <div id="content4" class="content">blahhhh</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.selected { color: #933; }
```